# Is there any way to take at first the arguments and at last the name in a function in racket?

Tags: operators, racket, postfix-mta, prefix

I was asked to write a program in racket in order to change the behaviours of arithmetic operators from prefix to postfix. More precisely:
I want this code:   `(a b +)`   to behave like:    `(+ a b)`

I wanted to use `define-syntax-rule` in order to change the behaviour of the + operator, but I have one problem, while using `define-syntax-rule` we write at first the name of our macro, and after that we write the arguments.
My question:  Is there any way to write the arguments at the beginning and the name at last in racket functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create your own [`#%app`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/application.html?q=%23%25app#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._%7E23%7E25app%29%29) macro. Since you are essentially creating a new language here, you'll want two modules: a 'lang' module that defines your language, and a 'use' module, for the program you want to write in that language. This could be done with two files, or one file using submodules.

Here, I'll show it to you using two files:

lang.rkt

```
#lang racket
(provide (except-out (all-from-out racket)
                     #%app)
         (rename-out [-app #%app]))
(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-syntax-parse-rule (-app args ... proc)
  (#%app proc args ...))
```

use.rkt

```
#lang s-exp "lang.rkt"
(3 2 +) ; => 5
```

Note though that this only changes function calls, not other forms. So:

use2.rkt

```
#lang s-exp "lang.rkt"
(define x 42)
(2 x *) ; => 84
```

Edit:

To explain what's happening in `lang.rkt`. It's taking the `racket` language, and re-exporting all of it, except the `#%app` macro. (For reference, all function applications in racket `(f args ...)` get expanded to `(#%app f args ...)`.)

For the `#%app` macro, we define another macro `-app`, which moves the function call from the end to the start, and the uses Racket's `#%app` macro. We then rename `-app` to `#%app` on export.

Section 5.1 of [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3110274) gives you an outline of the same thing, but to turn Racket into a lazy language.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has worked just fine. Can you breefly explain the code in lang.rkt ?

Comment: Sure! I edited the post to add an explanation.

Comment: @LeifAndersen, IIRC, `#lang s-exp` is not needed, right? You can just `require` it.

Comment: That is mostly correct. The reason I don't use `require` is because then you get a situation where `#%app` is different above the require (the original racket `#%app`, and below the require (the new `#%app`). Which I find leads to potentially confusing code.